# Bluetooth not getting enabled in Kali Linux inside Virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, bluetooth, kali-linux

I installed Virtualbox and set up kali Linux Yesterday. I wanted to connect my Bluetooth speaker. I went to the setting and tried to enable the button to turn on Bluetooth. But that button didn't work. Bluetooth section says "NO Bluetooth found. Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth".

My question is why do I need to use a dongle? My Bluetooth works fine when I am using Windows 10. But inside VirtualBox, I can't use Bluetooth. Why is it happening? How can I use Bluetooth in Kali Linux inside VirtualBox? Please provide me a solution to this problem.

Comment: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: See if it can be enabled as a device in the Kali Guest (VBOX function). Then 2 setting in Kali 2021.2 Settings: Bluetooth adapter and Bluetooth manager. See if these work and then if not you may need to add a Bluetooth device using USB Pass Through